# R: How can I make a new variable based on a percentage of four other variables?

Tags: r

I would like to compute country-specific weights based on the following elements: 40% population, 40% total GDP, 10% number of past applications and 10% unemployment rate.

My data looks like this:

```
Country   `Population (peop~ `Population (%):` `Total GDP (millio~ `Total GDP (%)` `Number of past appli~ `Number of past app~ `Unemployment rate (% ~
  <chr>                  <dbl>             <dbl>               <dbl>           <dbl>                  <dbl>                <dbl>                   <dbl>
1 Austria              8822267           0.0168                 113.          0.0324                 196875             0.0415                       4.9
2 Belgium             11398589           0.0216                 108.          0.0311                 126520             0.0266                       6  
3 Bulgaria             7050034           0.0134                 103.          0.0296                  57120             0.0120                       5.2
4 Croatia              4105493           0.00780                100.          0.0289                   4660             0.000981                     8.4
5 Cyprus                864236           0.00164                103.          0.0297                  19315             0.00407                      8.4
6 Czech Re~           10610055           0.0202                 115           0.0330                   7270             0.00153                      2.2
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question and thus [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Presumably you first normalize each of those columns (by dividing by their sum). That gives you proportions. Then you could directly sum those proportions for each row (country). You can do this in two lines with either `dplyr` or `data.table`. Please read the tutorials, try to write the code yourself and post the code here if you get stuck.

Comment: I recommend you read any good tutorial on either `dplyr` or `data.table` package, this is exactly what they're useful for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to assign different weights to the variables and calculate say a `new_var`, here is what you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
my_df <- read.csv("df.csv", header = T)
my_df %>% 
  mutate(new_var = ((.4*pop_per)+(.4*gdp_perc) + (.1*no_past_perc) + (.1*unRate)))
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Country population pop_per TotalGDP gdp_perc NoOfPastApplications no_past_perc unRate   new_var
# 1  Austria    8822267 0.01680      113   0.0324               196875     0.041500    4.9 0.5138300
# 2  Belgium   11398589 0.02160      108   0.0311               126520     0.026600    6.0 0.6237400
# 3 Bulgaria    7050034 0.01340      103   0.0296                57120     0.012000    5.2 0.5384000
# 4 Croatia     4105493 0.00780      100   0.0289                 4660     0.000981    8.4 0.8547781
# 5 Cyprus       864236 0.00164      103   0.0297                19315     0.004070    8.4 0.8529430
# 6 Czech Re   10610055 0.02020      115   0.0330                 7270     0.001530    2.2 0.2414330
```